# ASP.NET MVC implicitly adds route values

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I create ActionLink calling Html.ActionLink and passing route object to it. But looks like ASP.NET MVC implicitly adds other routes from current call.

For example, if I have two routes: "somepage/page/{page}" and "somepage" and currently user requested the page with the first root, "page" route value will be implicitly added to ActionLink and I can't create ActionLink to the second root.

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7133304/27938

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Url.Action adds current route values to generated url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133223/asp-net-mvc-url-action-adds-current-route-values-to-generated-url)