# In ASP.NET MVC 3, is there an easy way to create an html link copying the current URL and just changing one parameter?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page that displays some search options as links. Basically what these options do is just change a parameter of the current URL.

Of course I can iterate through the `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` and build another URL with the parameters changed but I was wondering if there's a better way to do that using some MVC feature.

Is there a way I can do that easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there isn't "simple way" becuase of the defualt values!
look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133223/asp-net-mvc-url-action-adds-current-route-values-to-generated-url)
But you can still use the @Url.Action and just change the params values, so it's still a "Simple way"