# Asp.net mvc Url.Action to redirect controller with nullable parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Load(Guid? id)
{
   ...
}
```

When load the view like `/Report/Load` it load the page.

Then I click on link on page to load one item `/Report/Load/7628EDFB-EFD5-E111-810C-00FFB73098ED` and it loads the page fine.

Now I want to redirect again to `/Report/Load` using this url.action

`<a href="@Url.Action("Load", "Report")">Close Report</a>`

But it keeps redirecting me to `/Report/Load/7628EDFB-EFD5-E111-810C-00FFB73098ED`

What I need to do on URL.Action to redirect me to page with the id?

Tried without success:

`<a href="@Url.Action("Load", "Report", null, null)">Close Report</a>`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Load", "Report", new { id = null })">Close Report</a>
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7133304/202913) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed by following answer from johnnyRose and Beyers.

The result is

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Load", "Report", new { id = "" }, null)">Close Report</a>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find issue with your code. But Can't you simply set the URL in the model when trying to load the specific item. 
In the load function inside the controller do something like this:

```
var urlBuilder =
new System.UriBuilder(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    {
        Path = Url.Action("Load", "Report"),
        Query = null,
    };

   Uri uri = urlBuilder.Uri;
  string url = urlBuilder.ToString();
  YourModel.URL = url;
```

In your view.cshtml do something like

```
  <a href="@Model.URL " target="_blank">reports</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have looked up in your vs's intellisense-

As it accepts arguments- `ActionName`,`ControllerName`,`RouteValues`

[image]

Where `routeValues` is the third argument that is `object` type and it accepts route values i.e. `new{id=9,name="foobar"}`

Where method would be like-

```
[HttpGet]
Public ActionResult Get(int id, string name)
{
}
```