# How to block access to controller via changing Url in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to access page  when user clicks to button.

By changing url, such as ..../Member/Batch/Create I want my site redirect user to another page.

How can I do this via ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1?

Comment: Check this [Redirect to Action in another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785245/redirect-to-action-in-another-controller/10785274)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean we could only access the controller by using button?

If this is your requirement, you could try to check the `Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString()` to make sure just which url could access this controller.

Like below:

```
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        var re = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
        if (Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString() != "https://localhost:44342/home/index")
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Batch", "Member", null)">Create Batch</a>
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7133304/202913) and [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) for more details.